# JDBC - ORACLE Connection Timeout parameter for Sqoop

Tags: oracle, jdbc, connection, timeout, sqoop

I am trying to set the timeout value(100 sec) for the JDBC connect URL. I thought of using ?param=value in the JDBC connection string for Sqoop, but I get errors like:

ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException:  NL Exception was generated
        java.sql.SQLException: NL Exception was generated
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)

I am using the below syntax:

```
    sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@<ip address>:<port>/<service-name>?oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT=100 --username <username>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the so-called long format URL to be able to set extra parameters. For example if you want to set the connection timeout to 10 seconds, please try:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=10)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=<ip address>)(PORT=<port>)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=<service-name))) --username <username>
```